# Getx snackbar appears only on the second time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, snackbar

I have this code that verify if an sms is sent multiple time, When I get a TooManyRequestsException  I want to show a snackbar that tells the user, the problem is that the snackbar doesn't show unless I call it for the second time.

**the code bellow doesn't work (snackbar doesn't appear) :**

```
on TooManyRequestsException  {
  CustomSnackBar.warning('exceeded_sms'.tr);
}
```

**the code bellow works (snackbar appear):**

```
on TooManyRequestsException {
  CustomSnackBar.warning('exceeded_sms'.tr);
  CustomSnackBar.warning('exceeded_sms'.tr);
}
```

**CustomSnackBar Class:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class CustomSnackBar {

  static const Duration _duration = Duration(milliseconds: 4000);

  static void warning(String text, {Duration duration = _duration}) {
    Get.snackbar('', '',
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        titleText: Container(),
        messageText: Text(
          text,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        duration: duration);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the snackbar appears as expected, 
you can use the await keyword to wait for the snackbar to be shown 
before proceeding with the rest of your code. 
Here's how you can modify your code:

```
try {
  // Your code to send SMS here
} on TooManyRequestsException {
  await CustomSnackBar.warning('exceeded_sms'.tr);
}
```